# What does 一个赛一个不讲理的 mean? Does the 的 determine its meaning?

Tags: translation, meaning, sentence-structure, phrase

> 一个赛一个不讲理的

Does it mean 'one competition, one unreasonable' or 'one is more unreasonable than the one before'?

Does the word '的' important in sentence like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[赛](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/js/8D5B.htm) is the same as [比](http://www.zdic.net/z/1c/js/6BD4.htm) in this case.

一个赛一个不讲理的
　　　↓
一个比一个不讲理的
　　　↓
一个比一个不讲理
　　　↓
One is more unreasonable than another is.

The word '的' is not important, and can be removed.

Comment: Do not agree. "一个赛一个不讲理" is abbreviation for "一个(不讲理的人)赛一个不讲理的(人)", in which 不讲理的 is a noun phrase. And “赛” can not be replaced with "比" without removing "的". Because "一个比一个不讲理" is abbreviation for "一个（人）比一个（人）不讲理", in which 不讲理 is an adjective.

Comment: I can understand why you interpreted in this way.
You explained it word by word, and do not know the source.
Please search on the Web.
When you read the article, you will know my answer is reasonable.
The author just used another word to replace the common one. (詼諧手法)

Comment: I see your point, if you are talking about the sentence in the web novel chapter 《逆天守妃·第82章》: "為蝦米她遇到的男的都是一個賽一個不講理的，還讓不讓人活了". In that case the whole phrase "一个赛一个不讲理" behaves like an adjective to decribe the type of people, and "的" is not part of this phrase...

Answer (score 3):

一个赛一个不讲理的
赛 means 'more than / better than'
不讲理的 means 'someone who is unreasonable'
so 一个赛一个不讲理的 means 'those people are unreasonable, and the degree of unreasonable is more and more'

Answer (score 0):

Here “赛” is “比得上”be comparable to；“胜” surpass, and not compare “比”.
“一个赛一个不讲理的”
The meaning is one person is rude and another is more rude than befor one.

Answer (score 0):

The translation would be (as a clause, not full sentence):

"...each one more unreasonable than the next."

Since 赛 here means 比得上。